# Sharing Electron main process

Tags: electron

I have multiple electron apps. One is the main app and several other feature apps. There are few buttons on the main app which will cause feature apps to open. The problem here is every app has a main process that is causing more CPU to be utilized. Is it possible to use only one main process and share the renderer process.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what it's designed for, take a look at this repo:

https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos/tree/master/renderer-process/windows

Answer (score 0):

Depends. If you have a single electron application, then you can have it displaying multiple browser windows, each with its own render process. But we can't separate main process and the render processes into different 'executables' and connect them.

I have one electron application running that 'hosts' several apps and the main app is a launcher that allows me to start them (it's a tray application). So all webapps are connected to the same main process.

Comment: It's actually possible to "connect" distinct Electron executables, a rudimentary but simple way would be to start HTTP servers and clients, and then let the distinct executables "discover" each other either by ad-hoc scanning, or by using a distinct master "client". A more advanced way would be using native IPC solutions (e.g. COM on Win).

Comment: Yeah, well. I believe that it works or one can make it work. But I bet, something will be extremly difficult. Like, nodeintegration for the disconnected renderers or access to the features from the `remote` object. I think, that's not worth the effort. Wrapping express in an electron app and ship it as a plain server, probably with a little bit of admin/maintanance UI sounds interesting though.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to do it. Really appreciate.